# Copy folder to destination with its folder structure

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-10, robocopy

I have a folder `foldertocopy` with files in it. It is inside a folder structure like so

```
D:\somefolder1
       |--somefolder2
              |--somefolder3
                     |--foldertocopy
```

There could be other files or folders in any of the folders above. I have a destination folder like so `E:\destinationfolder`

I want to copy `foldertocopy` along with its contents to `destinationfolder` with the folder structure of `foldertocopy` till the parent `somefolder2` so that at the end of copy it looks like so

```
E:\destinationfolder
          |--somefolder2
                 |--somefolder3
                        |--foldertocopy
```

I don't want any of the other files or folders to get copied. How do I go about it?

I have tried robocopy in Windows 10, but I am not able to get the command right.

`robocopy "D:\somefolder1\somefolder2\somefolder3\foldertocopy" "E:\destinationfolder" /E /LEV:3`

All it does is, copy all the contents of `foldertocopy` to `E:\destinationfolder`, without any folder structure.

Comment: What about `robocopy "D:\somefolder1\somefolder2\somefolder3\foldertocopy" "E:\destinationfolder\somefolder2\somefolder3\foldertocopy" /E`?

Comment: `xcopy /t /e "D:\somefolder1\somefolder2" "E:\destinationfolder\"` should do the trick for the structure; then xcopy the required directory.

Answer (score 0):

With `robocopy`, if you want to copy a folder instead of just its contents to another location, you need to append the source folder name to the desitination path, just as the comment above has indicated. This might be confusing since it's different from the `cp` in bash. Because you want to keep the folder structure of `foldertocopy` till the parent `somefolder2`, you can copy parent folder `somefolder2` instead:

```
robocopy "D:\somefolder1\somefolder2" "E:\destinationfolder\somefolder2" /E
```

This should do want you want.

A possible duplicate from superuser: https://superuser.com/q/1458627/1159469